# Removing duplicates from a table in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `TAB1` in DB2 as below:

```
ID              Status
_______________________
10              Open
8               Closed
7               Open
10              Closed
7               Open
9               Open
11              Open
5               Closed
_______________________
```

I want to remove duplicates from above table in a single sql query based on the following business rule:

1) If an `ID` is duplicated, remove the one with `Status` `Closed`. e.g. the entry `10` with `Closed` should be removed.

2) If an `ID` is duplicated and the `Status` is also same, all the duplicate entries should be removed. e.g. both the entries for `ID` `7` with `Status` `Open` should be deleted.

How can I achieve this in a single Delete query ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is almost a direct translation of your requirements:

```
delete from tab1
    where (tab1.status = 'closed' and
           exists (select 1
                   from tab1 t2
                   where t2.id = tab1.id and t2.status <> 'closed'
                  )
          ) or
          (select count(*)
           from tab1 t2
           where t2.id = tab1.id and t2.status = tab1.status
          ) > 1;
```